# Docker, NodeJs, Redis - Redis functioning but throwing out errors

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm running Docker with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
  vapp:
    build: .
    command: npm run nodemon-test
    container_name: vapp
    volumes:
    - .:/home/tringuyen/app
    - /home/tringuyen/app/node_modules
    - /abi:/abi
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    links:
    - redis:redis
    depends_on:
    - redis
```

Everything running fine, I can verify that redis is running, the redis host in NodeJs is also updated to `redis`. However this error keeps spitting out, does anyone know what is the reason and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
vapp         | Uncaught Exception:  { Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
vapp         |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
vapp         |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
vapp         |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
vapp         |   syscall: 'connect',
vapp         |   address: '127.0.0.1',
vapp         |   port: 6379 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `localhost` with `redis` in your nodejs application to refer to your database server.

Also you don't need the "link" section in your docker-compose.yml. (It will be deprecated soon)

If you say you already did this, then your container still uses an old image. So try cleaning your environment by removing any container and volumes and make sure the image is rebuild (`docker-compose up --build`).

When the application starts open a shell in that container and verify that the file where you define the database name is indeed updated.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, got it working, the error was from somewhere else which also calls a redis client, the host there wasn't updated to `redis`.